# ElasticSearch scripting - get unsorted array order

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, groovy

I have the following schema, where spending is an array.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "entityName": {
      "dynamic": "false",
      "properties": {
        "id":         { "type": "string",   "index": "not_analyzed" },
        "spending": {
          "dynamic": "false",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "start":    { "type": "date",  "index": "not_analyzed" },
            "end":      { "type": "date",  "index": "not_analyzed" },
            "amount":   { "type": "float", "index": "not_analyzed" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Everything works great until I try to access `spending.amount` in a groovy map script by its index with `doc['spending.amount'].values[i]` - it returns a different element and the `doc['spending.amount'].values` is actually sorted.

So, the question is: how do I access the original (unsorted) array?  I looked into [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html) and [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-fields.html) but whenever I used `ctx._source` all I got was

> No such property: ctx for class: 0c55d8cb3fce09491241ef9d60297789e92dee68

Thanks.